# RDF4J Ontotext GraphDB: prepareUpdate big Sparql-Update String-> Unsupported MIME type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, sparql, graphdb, rdf4j

Im trying to send a big Sparql-Update String to GraphDB by using RDF4J. It works for small Sparql-Update Strings, but for a big String (ca. 8000 INSERT DATA-Statements) it fails with the HTTP-Exception

```
org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.http.HTTPUpdateExecutionException: Unsupported MIME type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

My RDF4J code looks like this:

```
HTTPRepository repository = new HTTPRepository("http://localhost:7200", "test");
repository.initialize();
try (RepositoryConnection conn = repository.getConnection()) {
     conn.prepareUpdate(SPARLQString).execute();
}
```

I already tried to set the Header to "application/sparql-update" but i got the same exception.

Is this behavior intended?
How do i work around / fix this issue?

Ive used Fuseki before and never had this Problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTTPRepository(String repositoryURL) instead and it should work.

```
HTTPRepository repository = new HTTPRepository("http://localhost:7200/repositories/test");
```

For update operations the endpoint is /repositories/test/statements.

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion, but im still getting the same error. I also tried using plain rest to post the string to " /repositories/test/statements" resulting in the same error. Is there a max size configuration somewhere that i have to change?